# Reactjs Map Changes state of Props

Tags: reactjs

I have a react setup where I am attempting to change a layout based on a specific value. Before I can jump into incorporating a switch statement, I am trying to modify my current code to ensure that I can replace the array being mapped with one that would be used for a different layout and at the moment it looks like this change is changing the make up of the `this.props`element.

Here is the code:

```
export default class BlogFeed extends React.Component {
    ...
       render(){
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div>
            { 
                this.props.blogs.map((blog, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12 blog-card-container">
                                <BlogCard {...blog} key={blog.blogIdHash} user={this.props.user} />
                                <Comments comments={this.state.comments} key={index} blogId={blog.blogIdHash} csrf={this.props.csrf} userId={this.props.user.userIdHash} updateComments={this.updateCommentsFunc} deleteCommentFunc={this.deleteCommentsFunc} deletedCommentBlogId={this.state.deletedCommentBlogId} flash={this.state.flash} userId={this.props.user.userId}/> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When left as is, here is what `this.props` contains:

```
blogs: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
changeBlogs: [{…}]
csrf: "code"
feedPreference: 1
isLoading: false
negativeBlogs: [{…}]
notifications: [{…}]
onboardingWelcome: undefined
positiveBlogs: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

When I change `this.props.blogs.map` to `this.props.positiveBlogs.map` it breaks my JSX.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at BlogFeed.render (VM226 182:95)
    at finishClassComponent (VM81 80:10249)
    at updateClassComponent (VM81 80:10226)
    at beginWork (VM81 80:10605)
    at performUnitOfWork (VM81 80:12573)
    at workLoop (VM81 80:12682)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (VM81 80:1299)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (VM81 80:1338)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (VM81 80:1195)
    at performWork (VM81 80:12800)
```

and `this.props` now contains:

```
{blogs: Array(0), isLoading: true, onboardingWelcome: false, notifications: Array(0)}
```

What stands out is the `isLoading` state which is set a level up from this component and set to false when data is returned from the server, but the server is sending data just fine so I'm not sure why this might be impacted. I can provide the parent level component code if this is something that needs to be looked at to answer.

Comment: Can you set up a minimal, executable project that reproduces your problem? The above code doesn't really provide enough information.

Comment: You can call map on an empty array but it has to exist.
When loading, your component receives an empty *blogs* array but no *positiveBlogs*. Of course it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you want to render only `positiveBlogs`, you can do it like this:

`this.props.positiveBlogs && this.props.positiveBlogs.map(...`

This prevents render from calling the map when there is no array to work on.